# Contar o número de notas

Tags: java

O programa precisa que se digite o valor de notas. Quando digitar, o programa deve devolver numero de notas de 20,10,5 1

```
/* Code in Java */
import java.util.Scanner;

class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n;
        int notas[] = {20, 10, 5, 1};
        int numeroNotas[]={0,0,0,0};
        int i;
        System.out.println("Digite o numero:");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        while(n!=0){
            System.out.println("Digite o numero:");
            n = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for(i=0;i<=notas.length-1;i++){
            System.out.println(" notas de "+notas[i]+" ="+numeroNotas[i]);
        }
    }
    private static int conversor(int []notas,int n, int numeroNotas[]){

        int i=0;

        while(n%notas[i]==0){        
            i++;
        }
        numeroNotas[i]=numeroNotas[i]+1;

        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual é sua dúvida?

Comment: como retornar o numero de notas

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar o número de objetos da array (que no caso, é o número de notas), você usa o length.

Exemplo:

System.out.println(numeroDeNotas.length);